# Angular2: Just update the last segment of a route

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-route-segment

I've got a route in my app in the form `localhost/opportunity/:id/volunteers`. I want to build a `routerLink` to navigate to different pages on the same level (i.e. `localhost/opportunity/:id/waitlist`). Following the options outlined in the [API documentation for `Routerlink`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLink-directive.html), the impression I get is that a `routerLink` in the form `routerLink="./volunteers"` *should* link to the same page I am currently on. Therefore, `routerLinkActive` for `routerLink="./volunteers"` should indicate the link is active. But it doesn't do that...

The relevant routes look like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'opportunity',
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        children: [
          {
            path: 'volunteers',
            component: VolunteersComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'waitlist',
            component: WaitlistComponent
          },
          {
             etc . . .
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

The `routerLink="./volunteers"` appears to navigate to `localhost/volunteers`, which doesn't exist. I've also tried links in the form `routerLink="../../volunteers"`, `routerLink="../volunteers"`, `routerLink="././volunteers"`, etc (they don't work either, not that I thought they would).

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong? Obviously, I could extract the `:id` from the link manually and insert it (something like `routerLink="['opportunity', extractedId, 'volunteers']"`) but that feels like the wrong way and I'd like to not have to manually extract the `:id`'s all over my app. It seems likely I'm just doing something wrong. I've searched S.O. for a while, but haven't found an answer to this question.

*Small edit: let me also say that this module is loaded directly into the root module.*

**UPDATE:**

When I try a `routerLink="../"`, it shows as active for the `localhost/opportunity/:id/volunteers` url, but clicking on the link takes me back to the home page (i.e. `localhost/`). I'm pretty convinced that my router only thinks there is one child level in my app (i.e. `localhost/opportunity/:id/volunteers` and `localhost/calendar` appear to both be direct children of `localhost`. While `localhost/opportunity/:id/volunteers` should be a direct child of `localhost/opportunity/:id`. Do I need to load a route through through the `router`'s `forChild()` method for the `router` to view it as a child? Said another way, is it possible that, because all of this module's routes are loaded in the same `forChild()` block, they're being treated as the same level of child?

Answer (score 5):

If the current page is `/opportunity/321/volunteers`:

- `./volunteers` goes to `/opportunity/321/volunteers/volunteers`
- `volunteers` goes to `/opportunity/321/volunteers/volunteers`
- `../volunteers` goes to `/opportunity/321/volunteers`
- `/volunteers` goes to `/volunteers`
- `..` goes to `/opportunity/321`

The syntax you are looking for is then `../volunteers`.

**Update**

Your configuration is wrong.

With a single `<router-outlet>`, it should be:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'opportunity/:id/volunteers',
    component: VolunteersComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'opportunity/:id/waitlist',
    component: WaitlistComponent
  },
  {
    etc . . .
  }
];
```

You can use a child `<router-outlet>` with:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'opportunity/:id',
    component: OpportunityComponent
    children: [
      {
        path: 'volunteers',
        component: VolunteersComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'waitlist',
        component: WaitlistComponent
      },
      {
         etc . . .
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    etc . . .
  }
];
```

You then need an `OpportunityComponent` whose html must contain another `<router-outlet>`

The `OpportunityComponent` then goes into the app `<router-outlet>`, and the `VolunteersComponent` goes into the `<router-outlet>` inside the `OpportunityComponent`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried that. It doesn't work. It definitely seems like it should, which is why I included my routes in case there's some config I missed?

Comment: Ok, this is weird. Your question prompted me to try a `routerLink="../"`. That routerLink shows as active for the `localhost/opportunity/:id/volunteers` url, but *clicking* on the link takes me back to the home page (just `localhost/`). I'm pretty convinced that my router only thinks there is one child level in my app (i.e. `localhost/opportunity/:id/volunteers` and `localhost/calendar` appear to both be direct children of `localhost`. While I would expect `localhost/opportunity/:id/volunteers` to be a child of `localhost/opportunity/:id`.